# Can't cast to generic type c#

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following scenario

```cs
public class A
{
}

public class BA : A
{

}

//other subtypes of A are defined

public class AFactory
{
    public T Create<T>() where T : A
    {
        //work to calculate condition
        if (condition)
            return new BA();
        //return other subtype of A
    }
}
```

The following compilation error is thrown:

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'B' to 'T'

What's wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why should this work? Both `B` and `T` are subtypes of `A` but that does not mean that `B` and `T` are the same...

Comment: It looks like you changed a lot in [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34267863/3), it's really hard to follow the answers under this question; can you revert back to that revision with the edits others have provided to fix the formatting and tags?

Answer (score 8):

Well the cast could easily fail. Suppose I have:

```
public class AB : A {}

B b = new B();
AB ab = b.Create<AB>();
```

That would end up trying to assign a `B` reference to a variable of type `AB`. Those are incompatible.

It sounds like you probably shouldn't make `Create` a generic method. Or *maybe* you should make `A` generic:

```
public abstract class A<T> where T : A
{
    public abstract T Create();
}

public class B : A<B>
{
    public override B Create()
    {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

That would work - but we don't know what you're trying to achieve, so it may not actually help you.

Alternatively you *could* keep your current design, but use:

```
public T Create<T>() where T :  A
{
    return (T) (object) new B();
}
```

That will then fail if you call `Create` with a type argument of anything other than `object`, `A` or `B`, which sounds a little odd to me...

Comment: I think you meant `public class B : A<B>` not `public class B : T<B>`.

Answer (score 1):

`T` can be any class derived from `A`. There could also be a

```
class C : A { }
```

It matches the generic constraint, but you can't return an instance of `B` from `Create<C>()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Right. For creating new B class you should use this code:

```
public class A
{
}

public class B : A
{
    public static T Create<T>() where T : A, new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}

public class Example
{
    public void DoWork()
    {

        B b = B.Create<B>();
        A a = B.Create<A>();
    }
}
```